# Turing machine on input w tries to move its head past the left end of the tape

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, undecidability

Consider the language

> $$ L = \{ \langle M,w \rangle \mid \text{$M$  on input $w$ tries to move its head past the left end of the tape}\}. $$

Prove whether L is decidable or not.

I tried to prove it as undecidable through reduction method but could'nt reduce the language halt to L inorder to prove that it is undecidable.

Comment: I think you should try harder. Already solved two questions for you. Now it's time for you to do the rest on your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
Construct Turing Machine M':
        On input x: Ignore the input x
        Simulate the run of machine M on w a separate tape
        If M accepts or reject: 
             Move the head of M' left
        Else: 
             Do Nothing
```

The machine M' described above will "try" to move the head on left only if M halts on w.

If L is decidable, then we can check for membership of $(M',\epsilon)$; but that will decide that $M$ halts on $w$ (The Halting Problem).

Hence, the language L is undecidable.